# Excel - precise positioning for printing

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, printing

I have some data created in Excel 2010. I planned to use Excel as printing software but I need to print over already printed paper with precisely designated places on these paper form (instead printing like plain table rows and columns). I made margins 1 cm but wasn't able to put some ActiveX Textbox controls with data right on certain vertical & horizontal position in order to get printing on correct position on paper form. 
Is it possible or I need to use some plug-in or additional software?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for bare Excel:
Adjust first column and row width and height to get column two and row two into correct position.

Hopefully you can match the row height (of the following lines) to the line height on the form and column width to also match the form in a similar way.

If that is not possible, then you might need to continue in the initial style, i.e. using every other row and column to adjust positions for the data you wish to print. In this case even more complex "tweaks" might be necessary.

Another alternative / help: use a monospace typeface (Courier, without "New" in the name).